# How can i get multiple value from an input field using javascript

Tags: javascript

In my code, I have an add function when user click on it. it will capture the user input value from the text and show. any idea how can I do it using javascript

```js
var split = ['S','M', 'L'];
for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
  var t = document.getElementById('text-box');
  t.innerHTML += 'Size <input value=' + split[i] + ' type="text">Description<input type="text" name="vrow" id="price">'
}
function add(){
//get the description value

}
```

```html
<div id="text-box">
</div>
<button onclick="add()">ADD</button>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. How can an input field hold multiple values? And what does the add() function do? And if it's just displaying values, why call it add() and not show(). Are you trying to confuse your future self (or colleagues)???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna take the value of all inputs of description, can use a class, to get all and iterate

```
 var split = ['S','M', 'L'];
for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
  var t = document.getElementById('text-box');
  t.innerHTML += 'Size <input value=' + split[i] + ' type="text">Description<input type="text" class="description-input" name="vrow" id="price">' 
}
function add(){

  const inputs=document.querySelectorAll('.description-input')
  inputs.forEach((input,index)=>{
    
    alert(`value of ${index} description is ${input.value}`)
    
  })
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Using Vanilla/plain JavaScript)

First add **id** attribute to field, like

```
First Name: <input type="text" name="f_name" id="f_name_id">
```

Then

```
document.getElementById("f_name_id").value
```

Make sure each field have a unique id.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick way to get all the values in a form as long as you give each input a "name" it will create a JS object for you.

This way you don't have to call each individual input value.
It will also work no matter how many divs or formating elements you have in the form as well.

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input name="firstname">
    <input name="lastname">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>
    document.querySelector("#myForm").addEventListener('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var obj = {};
        event.target.querySelectorAll('input','select','textarea')
            .forEach((v)=>{
                if(v.type !== 'sumbit' && v.name){
                    obj[v.name] = v.value
                }
            });
        console.log(obj);
        /* obj
            {
                firstname: "",  
                lastname: "",
            }
        */
    })
</script>
```